# How to represent a parameterized type in Python?

Tags: python, haskell, python-typing

In Haskell, `foldm` (the monad version of `foldl`) has this type.

`foldM :: (Monad m) => (a -> b -> m a) -> a -> [b] -> m a`

(See [this](https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads#Monadic_versions_of_list_functions), for example.)

A Python equivalent might be declared like this.

```
a = TypeVar('a')
b = TypeVar('b')
def foldM(f: Callable[[a, b], Monad], acc: a, xs: List[b]) -> Monad:
    ...
```

A problem with this is that it doesn't show `Monad` as parameterized by type `a`. I'd like to write `Monad[a]`, but that is not valid. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What *is* `Monad`? It's not in [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). And what do you mean *"not valid"*? Give a [mcve].

Comment: might also depend on what you actually use for typechecking (`mypy` vs PyCharm IDE etc.) see https://medium.com/@ageitgey/learn-how-to-use-static-type-checking-in-python-3-6-in-10-minutes-12c86d72677b#c3b1

Answer (score 2):

Have `Monad` inherit from `Generic`:

```
from typing import TypeVar, List, Callable, Generic

a = TypeVar('a')
b = TypeVar('b')

class Monad(Generic[a]):
    # your code here
    pass

def foldM(f: Callable[[a, b], Monad[a]], acc: a, xs: List[b]) -> Monad[a]:
    # your code here
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that Monad is defined in a library and is not my code. (I should have mentioned that in the question.)

Comment: @RussAbbott You'll probably have to define your own type-hint proxy for `Monad`, just as `typing` provides `List` for `[]` (and other list-like types).

Comment: @chepner, Do you have a suggestion about what that might look like?

Comment: `class MonadType(Generic[a]): pass` might suffice.